# Execute a function periodically, with the period being dynamic

Tags: python, multithreading, heartbeat

I'm trying to execute a "heartbeat" function every "x" seconds. However, this "x" needs to be variable and changed dynamically when certain conditions are met. How can I do this elegantly in python?

The simplest idea I can think of is to use a `while True` loop in a thread that sleeps for "x" seconds. And then this variable can be updated within the thread when needed so that the next sleep call is for the new "x" seconds.

I'm not sure if this approach is the most optimal way to achieve the heartbeat and heartbeat "racing" that I want. I would appreciate any helpful insights here, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure sleep plays well with multithreading.

Comment: There's a https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html - you can even look at its implementation: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/sched.py

Comment: To avoid short sleeps just to check if something changes, you can use a threading.Event to notify you when the value changes.

Comment: I thought sleep() just blocks the current thread, and the other running threads are unaffected?

Comment: I need the thread to read and write from/to a database every "x" seconds. But when a certain condition is met, these actions need to happen faster, hence my need to change the value of "x".

Comment: What are the interval limits (min and max)? What is the resolution required?

Comment: min would be around 1-2 seconds and max would be 20 seconds.